# Align 2 buttons vertically one above other?

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons, which currently is setted as follow :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/ff2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"          
          android:text="Cars"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/ff3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"          
          android:text="Options"/>
```

- How to align 2 buttons in right top corner one above other

Comment: use a LinearLayout and set its orientation to vertical. add buttons to linearlayout. You can also use relative layout.

Comment: if you are using rel layout already use also android:alignParentTop=true which will make then go to top right with what you alredy have.. you also can use android:below to make them appear one below the other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use LinearLayout for this

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `RelativeLayout` with `layout_below` property

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<Button android:id="@+id/ff2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"          
          android:text="Cars"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/ff3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below = "@id/ff2"
          android:text="Options"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

put both inside a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation and give to it as gravity `top|left`

Comment: +1 i guess it would be better if you had posted a sample xml layout with linear layout

Comment: @Raghunandan for implementation see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/ff2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"          
          android:text="Cars"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/ff3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ff2"
          android:layout_below = "@id/ff2"
          android:text="Options"/>
```